# Second group cohomology $H^2(\mathbb Z^n, \mathbb C^*)=?$

Tags: group-cohomology, integer-lattices

Regard $\mathbb Z^n$ as an abelian group, and let $\mathbb C^* = \mathbb C-\{0\}$.

**Question**: What is the group cohomology $H^2(\mathbb Z^n, \mathbb C^*)$?

More specific question is as follows. I have found out that for $n=2$, a map $f: \mathbb Z^2 \times \mathbb Z^2 \to \mathbb C^*$, defined as
$$f((m_1, m_2), (n_1, n_2)) = (-1)^{m_2n_1},$$
becomes a 2-cocyle, by explicitly checking all cases in Mathematica. Is $f$ 2-coboundary? (The motivation for finding an example $f$ comes from the "Jordan-Wigner string" in physics.)

Edit: The 2nd group cohomology $H^2(G,A)$ is related to the central extension of $G$ by an abelian group $A$. Define
$$Z_2(G,A) = \{ \omega: G\times G \to A: \omega(x,y) \omega(xy, z) = \omega(x, yz) \omega(y,z), \omega(1,1)=1\}.$$
Also, for a function $\lambda: G \to A$ with $\lambda(e)=e$, define $\omega_\lambda(x,y) = \lambda(x) \lambda(y) \lambda(xy)^{-1}$. Also, define
$$B_2(G,A) = \{\omega_\lambda: G \times G \to A\}_{\lambda:G\to A}.$$
The second cohomology is defined as $H^2(G,A) = Z_2(G,A)/B_2(G,A)$.

Comment: How does $\mathbb{Z}^n$ act on $\mathbb{C}^*$? Trivially?

Comment: @Mindlack Well, I don't understand your question. Here, my second group cohomology is related to the central extension of the group $\mathbb Z^n$ by $\mathbb C^*$. I will edit the post to include the definition of $H^2(\mathbb Z^n, \mathbb C^*)$.

Comment: A cohomology group $H^n(G,A)$ requires an action of $G$ on the abelian group $A$. Often this action is the trivial action and therefore is left unmentioned. If your problem is related to central extensions then that is most likely what you're looking for.

Comment: @CaptainLama Thanks for your comment. I edited to state the definition of $H^2(G,A)$, and I am not sure where the action of $G$ on $A$ is needed.

Comment: In general if you had an action of $G$ on $A$ you would get $x\cdot \omega(y,z)$ and $x\cdot \lambda(y)$ instead of $\omega(y,z)$ and $\lambda(y)$ in your two formulas. But here your formulas correspond to the case where this action is trivial, as one would have expected.